# Why do some statements fail to execute when run in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have trouble understanding the program behaviour of [this code sample](http://rustbyexample.com/channels.html):

```
use std::comm;
use std::thread::Thread;

static NTHREADS: uint = 3;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<uint>, Receiver<uint>) = comm::channel();

    for id in range(0, NTHREADS) {
        let thread_tx = tx.clone();

        Thread::spawn(move || {
            thread_tx.send(id);
            println!("thread {} finished", id);
        }).detach();
    }

    let mut ids = Vec::with_capacity(NTHREADS);
    for _ in range(0, NTHREADS) {
        ids.push(rx.recv());
    }

    println!("{}", ids);
}
```

Specifically, I don't understand why some tasks fail to reach this line when being detached:

```
println!("task {} finished", id);
```

But not when when joined with the parent (main).

Also, why is it that only joined tasks are executed in pre-defined order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code multiple times because the order of execution of the threads is not guaranteed. I also don't know how many concurrent processors that online evaluation is allowed, so you might be running it in a single-core machine. I ran it a few times on my multi-core laptop and got the following output:

```
task 0 finished
task 1 finished
task 2 finished
[0, 1, 2]

task 1 finished
task 0 finished
task 2 finished
[0, 1, 2]

task 0 finished
task 1 finished
[0, 1, 2]
task 2 finished
```

An important consideration with threads is that the program finishes *when the main thread finishes*. In this case, there are 4 threads to consider: the main thread and 3 task threads. The main thread will be done once it has received 3 messages and printed them out. It doesn't matter what the rest of the threads are doing!

When you `join` a thread from the main thread, you are telling the main thread to wait until the worker thread has exited. This means that each thread will be able to execute the `println!` before the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not join tasks but detaches it. This means the tasks are independent of the main thread (the one that detaches it)

Then two options for each task:

- it is finished before the println is executed: then you see it in the code via the print
- it is not finished and then the println you mentionned is executed **without waiting for it**

If you join then it means "I have to wait for this task to carry on". Therefore all the task are executed before the line is executed.

There is no predefined order, which makes multi-threaded code hard to debug :-)

Comment: How is it possible for task to finish before executing it's code?

Comment: Since 'println!("task {} finished", id);' is part of task's code body, how is it possible for a task to '(be) finished before the println is executed'?

Comment: because it is executed in another part of the program and in parallel, ie a thread. That is what a thread is used for. Use join to force it to finish before you carry on

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say: "Then two options for each task... it is finished before the println is executed". How does the fact that it's executed in parallel to the parent task (main) create a possibility for it is killed off before it gets a chance to finish?

Comment: once the main thread finishes, the programs stops so if a detached thread is not finished you don't see its results

Comment: I've got confused with pronouns in your original answer, but I think I get it now, thanks.