# How is 999µs too short but 1000µs just right?

Tags: linux, rust, rust-obsolete

When I run the following code, I get `some output`:

```
use std::thread::Thread;

static DELAY: i64 = 1000;

fn main() {
    Thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("some output");
    });

    std::io::timer::sleep(std::time::duration::Duration::microseconds(DELAY));
}
```

But if I set `DELAY` to 999, I get nothing. I think that 999 and 1000 are close enough not to cause such a difference, meaning there must be something else going on here. I've tried also with `Duration::nanoseconds` (999_999 and 1_000_000), and I see the same behavior.

My platform is Linux and I can reproduce this behavior nearly all the time: using 999 results in `some output` in way less than 1% of runs.

---

As a sidenote, I am aware that this approach [is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27770032).

Comment: Can you reliable reproduce this, across different workloads and sessions? And what's your exact platform? I think the answer may well be hidden in your operating system's scheduler rather than any Rust code.

Comment: "I can reproduce this very reliably, but it doesn't happen 100% of the time." how reliable is that ?

Comment: @exussum: That must be 99% of the time ;-)

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on [play.rust-lang.org](http://is.gd/er2Xc1) (Try changing `+ 1` to `+ 0`).

Comment: That's why you shouldn't just guess when things are done, but check it (I've never done rust, so I don't know if the following piece of code is actually (thread-)safe, but it definitely works something along that way): [play.rust-lang.org](http://is.gd/KcHr3P). You may use a [condvar](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) for this to make it beautiful

Comment: I think this will boil down to things like "what version and options was your kernel compiled with" and "how many other programs are you running at the same time" and "what process scheduler are you using with what options". Said another way, there's probably some setting somewhere that schedules threads that happens to do one thing for >= 1ms and another for < 1ms.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with this? https://gist.github.com/rninty/c15c45afe5e570e139cf

Comment: @stefan Your playpen example goes into an infinite loop - `done` is not shared between the threads because of `move`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner As I said: never done anything with rust before. But this should be possible with a condvar as I also said.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner http://is.gd/UeaN62 I gather that's a valid approach, is it?

Comment: @stefan it's probably easier to use a [channel](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html), but that's starting to get into a new question that I'd encourage you to ask separately!

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not actually interested in this. I just wanted to point out that there are ways (no matter how they are called in this language and no matter which one is optimal) to actually do this properly ;-)

Comment: @stefan Your solution with the condvar looks perfectly valid to me. A channel may be simpler, but this works perfectly fine.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE I can't, even when using 1 as an argument. Also, I sometimes get 2 `some output` lines with that code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `sleep` function sleeps in increments of 1 millisecond, and if the number of milliseconds is less than 1 it does not sleep at all. Here is the relevant [excerpt from the code](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/timer.rs.html#98-103):

```
pub fn sleep(&mut self, duration: Duration) {
    // Short-circuit the timer backend for 0 duration
    let ms = in_ms_u64(duration);
    if ms == 0 { return }
    self.inner.sleep(ms);
}
```

In your code, 999 microseconds made it not sleep at all, and the main thread ended before the spawned thread could print its output. With 1000 microseconds, i.e. 1 millisecond, the main thread slept, giving the spawned thread a chance to run.

Answer (score -3):

The most probable thing is you have your kernel configured to have a TICK of 1000Hz (once clock interrupt per millisecond)  Perhaps you can improve it recompiling on a finer grained clock or a tickless kernel and recompiling your kernel to allow finer clock resolution.  The 1000Hz clock tick is nowadays standard in Linux kernels running on pc (and most of ARMs and embedded Linux).

This is not a newbie issue, so perhaps you'll have to ask for local help to reconfigure and recompile your kernel to cope with more time resolution.

Comment: that's not a reason to downvote... If it where, the thread might be closed and not allow more comments.  I try to give some help, not to read all stackoverflow before answering.

Comment: The Answer I'm referring to was already Accepted on the Question you were Answering.